# php echo image with single and double quotes doesn't not work

Tags: php, echo

How do I get this example echo image to work single and double?

```
data-mean="<?php 
    echo 
    '<div>' . $k["auto_ans"][$i] . '</div>' .
    '<div><img src=' . $k["auto_image"][$i] . '></div>' . 
    '<div><img src=' . $k["auto_image2"][$i] . '></div>'; ?>"
```

I want it to output:

```
data-mean="<div>AAAA</div><div><img src='aaa.jpg'></div><div><img src='bbb.jpg></div>"
```

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: @Chris i update my question

Comment: Does src require quotes around its value ie. SRC="blah.jpg"> ?

Comment: Learn how strings work http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put quotes around SRC prop like this :

```
data-mean="<?php 
echo 
'<div>' . $k["auto_ans"][$i] . '</div>' .
'<div><img src=\'' . $k["auto_image"][$i] . '\'></div>' . 
'<div><img src=\'' . $k["auto_image2"][$i] . '\'></div>'; ?>"
```